# lock in java multithreading is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

```
  //I have this main class

    package IntroductionLocks;

    public class Intro {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            NoLockATM noLockATM = new NoLockATM();
            LockedATM lockedATM = new LockedATM();
            MyClass thread1 = new MyClass(noLockATM, lockedATM);
            MyClass thread2 = new MyClass(noLockATM, lockedATM);

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            thread1.waitUntilDone();
            thread2.waitUntilDone();

            System.out.println("NoLock ATM: " + noLockATM.getBalance());
            System.out.println("Locked ATM: " + lockedATM.getBalance());
            int v = thread1.delta + thread2.delta + 100;
            System.out.println("Should Be: " + v);
            System.out.println("Program terminating.");
        }

    }


    //// 2nd class

    package IntroductionLocks;

    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    import CtCILibrary.AssortedMethods;

    public class MyClass extends Thread  {
        private NoLockATM noLockATM;
        private LockedATM lockedATM;
        public int delta = 0;

        private Lock completionLock;

        public MyClass(NoLockATM atm1, LockedATM atm2) {
            noLockATM = atm1;
            lockedATM = atm2;
            completionLock = new ReentrantLock();
        }

        public void run() {
    //question here
            completionLock.lock();
            int[] operations = {10,20};//AssortedMethods.randomArray(20, -50, 50);
            for (int op : operations) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                delta += op;
                if (op < 0) {
                    int val = op * -1;
                    noLockATM.withdraw(val);
                    lockedATM.withdraw(val);
                } else {
                    noLockATM.deposit(op);
                    lockedATM.deposit(op);              
                }
            }
            completionLock.unlock();
        }

        public void waitUntilDone() {
            completionLock.lock();
            completionLock.unlock();
        }
    }


//// 3rd class LockedATM

package IntroductionLocks;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockedATM {
    private Lock lock;
    private int balance = 100;

    public LockedATM() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public int withdraw(int value) {
        lock.lock();
        int temp = balance;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            temp = temp - value;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            balance = temp;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      }
        lock.unlock();
        return temp;
    }

    public int deposit(int value) {
        lock.lock();
        int temp = balance;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            temp = temp + value;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            balance = temp;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      }
        lock.unlock();
        return temp;
    } 

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

my question is...why completionLock.lock() in run method is not locking the resource. When i run the program, in System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName())

i get below output:
Thread-1
        Thread-0
        Thread-0
        Thread-1
        NoLock ATM: 130
        Locked ATM: 160
        Should Be: 160
        Program terminating.

```
    `enter code here`isnt lock supposed to lock the resource....that mean only one thread can get access to it at a time.....????? then why it is showing that first thread 1 is getting acces then thread 0 then again thread 0 and then thread1 ???

   Isnt only thread1/0 should get first completed than other??
```

Also what is wait until done is supposed to do???

Answer (score 1):

Each of your runnables has it's own lock object. That is the answer.
You need to have a shared lock. Or use one of your `ATM` objects as lock

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the usage of the Reentrant lock. In your case, each instance of MyClass thread will have its own instance of the completionLock. For you to synchronize the 2 instances of MyClass thread you should be using a shared object. Create the completionLock instance in the main method and pass the instance to both the threads

```
new MyClass(noLockATM, lockedATM, completionLock);

public MyClass(NoLockATM atm1, LockedATM atm2, ReentrantLock completionLockArg) {
         this.noLockATM = atm1;
         this.lockedATM = atm2;
         this.completionLock = completionLockArg; 
}
```

Comment: so because whenever myclass constructor is being called, a new lock gets created due to completionLock = new ReentrantLock();...
So what i deduce from that is....locking of resource depends on instance of class....here in my case..there are 2 instance of myclass, and for both to be synchronize, both of then should have same lock object????
correct me if i am wrong..

also can u point out the significance of waituntildone method??

Comment: Yes.. you got it right.. for any set of threads to work in a synchronized way., it has to be on a lock object which is accessible to all the threads.  Also, I don’t see any significance of waitUntilDone method which you have declared. It justs locks and unlocks the reentrant lock and doesn’t help for synchronization in any way.